# Please explain this question in an easy way

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

I just started study of Graph Theory with no instructor. I am stuck at above example question. Though explaination have been given in the book I cannot get it.

Isn't the rightmost people getting two jobs?

Isn't leftmost job is assigned to two people?

Comment: yes !, but these are **all** possibility can you pick a good one, that give a job to a person that can do it ?

Comment: @Ahmad why second rightmost can't do second leftmost job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph models what people are qualified to do what job.  What you are seeing is one person qualified for multiple jobs, and one job that many people are qualified for.

The goal is to select edges such that each person gets a distinct job.

The point is that it cannot be done for this particular graph.  The leftmost two jobs are the only jobs that three workers can do (the leftmost two workers and the rightmost worker.) So it is obvious those two jobs can't be distributed to three people.

Another way to see it is that the third person is the only one qualified for two jobs... and obviously he can't get assigned both.